# Create a simple guard in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware, laravel-guard

I am trying to implement a very simple authentication mechanism with Laravel.

I need to protect certain routes so they are viewable from a specific IP address.

I want to do this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != '123.45.67.89') {
    return Redirect::away('some url');
}
```

How can I implement this with a guard?

Comment: Read [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication#adding-custom-guards), implement your guard, ask again with any code you have that has errors/warnings/doesn't work as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware) as it's used for what you're trying to do.

Create a new middleware by doing `php artisan make:middleware SimpleGuardMiddleware`. It will be created in `app\Http\Middleware\SimpleGuardMiddleware.php`.

Then, in the file you can write something like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->ip() != '123.45.67.89') {
        return Redirect::away('some url');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

And then, go to `app\Http\Kernel.php`, make sure to add this to your `protected $routeMiddleware` array.

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    //.. your previous files ...
    'myguard' => SimpleGuardMiddleware.php::class,
];
```

And then in your route file, you can do something like

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    // your routes here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Taylor. I already implemented this with middleware. Can I implement this with a guard?